# How to use the json?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have called an api using href from the html form and it in response gives json as output.
consider this as the json the api gives

```
{
"entry":
{
"id": "1",
"name": "SA"
}
}
```

I want the values of the id and name.
How can i get the values specifically and store those values to a variable.
Also i got to do this in the html form with javascript.

Answer (score 3):

> I want the values of the city_id and city_name. How can i get the
>   values specifically and store those values to a variable

Use `JSON.parse` to convert it to JS object and get your values:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(yourJSON);
var city_id = obj['entry']['city_id'];
var city_name = obj['entry']['city_name'];
```

**Docs:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Answer (score 0):

```
var a;
eval('a={"entry":{"@collection_url":"http://api.storageroomapp.com/accounts/4fe004c598f46026cc000002/collections/4fe0063798f4602e2c000016","@created_at": "2012-06-21T09:12:40Z","@trash": false,"@type": "City","@updated_at": "2012-06-21T09:12:40Z","@url":"http://api.storageroomapp.com/accounts/4fe004c598f46026cc000002/collections/4fe0063798f460e2c000016/entries/4fe2e58898f4604757000006","@version": 1,"city_id": "City_001","city_name": "London"}}');
```

---

in other words

```
eval ('a={/*response object*/}')
```

now you have (a) as object that contains your data you can access them whether like object notation (a.entry) or as an array (a['entry'])
you can also use json parse but its not compatible with all browsers

Answer (score 0):

Either the eval() function or the JSON parser will allow you to create an object from the JSON and then access the fields normally.  The JSON parser is a little more secure, as explained in this tutorial:

http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_eval.asp